# convert normal html table into datatable

Tags: php, search, datatable

I want too convert normal table in html to datatable so that i can get more options like

1. sorting
2. pagination
3. searching

How can i do this?
this is my code for table.

```
 <table id="payment">    
    <thead class="bg-danger">
        <th>S NO</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Voucher No</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> 1 </td>
            <td> 16/03/2020</td>
            <td> 12345</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> 2 </td>
            <td> 17/03/2020</td>
            <td> 98765</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: the table also have id="payment"

Answer (score 1):

Just go to [the main web-page](https://datatables.net/) and explore it.

Below a simple example of possible DataTable with your table code.

```js
$(()=>{
    $('#payment').DataTable();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css"/>

<table id="payment">    
    <thead class="bg-danger">
        <th style="width:200px;">S NO</th>
        <th style="width:200px;">Date</th>
        <th style="width:200px;">Voucher No</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> 1 </td>
            <td> 16/03/2020</td>
            <td> 12345</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> 2 </td>
            <td> 17/03/2020</td>
            <td> 98765</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this is a good starting example like the @Aksen P suggested and it will work nicely with a small data set. But if you want optimal performances you will need to look at datatable ajax call to make proper pagination and searching as to not create big load times on your site when working with large data sets.

Comment: @IgorIlic, yes, you're right. There's much more possibilities to use this plugin.